# Multiple level quick launch navigation

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, navigation, quick-launch, team-sites

I know I can achieve a 2-level navigation, but can I add next level? So that I can have `02_Management report -> 99_Knowledge base -> 01_Main principle`?

[image]

Comment: Are you using modern team site?

Comment: The homepage is modern, but settings are classic.

Comment: Did you activate publishing site feature on your site?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer to your question is **Yes**. In SharePoint online modern experience, you can have 3 levels of navigation links:

Sample:

[image]

You can either drag & drop links to make it as a child link OR you can select ellipses (`...`) against navigation link and select **Make sub link**.

Comment: I went to navigation settings, added a folder into 2nd level and added new URL on level 3, but after clicking on `OK` the site crashes.

Comment: Are you using classic experience?

Comment: `modern-experience` tag says nothing to you?

Comment: Did you enable publishing feature on your site? I am asking this because you don't need to go to navigation settings.

Comment: Hi @MartinDub, does this answer help you in any way? If yes, Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily. It also removes this question from "Unanswered questions" list.